# Matplotlib, Set multiple parameters at once?

Tags: python, graph, parameters, matplotlib, default

Is there a way to set parameters for multiple graphs at once - basically defining a default?

What I have right now:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ax1.scatter(entries,gvalues[0], color='b', marker = '1')
ax1.scatter(entries,gvalues[1], color = 'g', marker = 'v')
xticks([z for z in range(N)], namelist)
ylabel('Label1', ha='center', labelpad=28)
ylim(0,)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312, sharex=ax1)
ax2.scatter(entries,gvalues[2], color = 'b', marker = '1')
ax2.scatter(entries,gvalues[3], color= 'g', marker = 'v')
ylabel('Label2', ha='center', labelpad=28)
setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(),visible=False)
ylim(0,)
```

I am going to have a handful of these graphs, and it would be great if I didn't have to set `ha = 'center', labelpad = 28` and `ylim(0,)` everytime.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store your options as below:

```
font_options = dict(ha='center', labelpad=28)

ax1.set_ylabel('Label1', **font_options)

...

ax2.set_ylabel('Label2', **font_options)
```

The `**font_options` argument will unpack each of the key-value pairs in the dictionary and apply them within the `ylabel` function.

Similarly for the `ylim` option you can store your limits in a variable such as:

```
ylimit = 0

ylim(ylimit,)
```